# how to convert complete column to datatype of first non null value

Tags: python

Ik have a query that pivots certain features if available and form a dataframe in python.
It output something like:

[image]

It shows the first column as date and the second as integer but is says the other features are objects. Is there a way to automatic find the datatype of the first non null value in a column and convert the complete column to this datatype?
I allready tried df1.convert_dtypes().dtypes but this makes it all strings. There is not a row that doesn't contain nulls.

Answer (score 0):

**Possible (quick) solution is the following:**

```
# pip install pandas

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#set test data and create dataframe
data = {'Startdate': 
        ['01-01-2020', '01-02-2020', '01-03-2020', '01-04-2020', '01-05-2020', '01-06-2020', '01-07-2020'], 
        'personal number': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 'feature 1': ['76.4', np.nan, np.nan, '12.1', '58.4', np.nan, '36.4'], 
        'feature 2': ['26-12-1994', np.nan, '04-03-2022', '31-12-2011', np.nan, '03-10-1992', np.nan],
        'feature 3': ['M', 'V', np.nan, 'V', 'M', np.nan, 'V'],
        'feature 4': ['4','5','9',np.nan,'8','6','3']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Startdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Startdate'], format='%d-%m-%Y')

df.info()
```

Returns

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 7 entries, 0 to 6
Data columns (total 6 columns):
 #   Column           Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------           --------------  -----         
 0   Startdate        7 non-null      datetime64[ns]
 1   personal number  7 non-null      int64         
 2   feature 1        4 non-null      object        
 3   feature 2        4 non-null      object        
 4   feature 3        5 non-null      object        
 5   feature 4        6 non-null      object        
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(1), object(4)
memory usage: 464.0+ bytes
```

**Option 1: 'Manually' convert columns values to the required type**

```
df['feature 1'] = df['feature 1'].astype(float)
df['feature 2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['feature 2'], format='%d-%m-%Y')
df['feature 4'] = df['feature 4'].astype(float)

df.info()
```

Returns

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 7 entries, 0 to 6
Data columns (total 6 columns):
 #   Column           Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------           --------------  -----         
 0   Startdate        7 non-null      datetime64[ns]
 1   personal number  7 non-null      int64         
 2   feature 1        4 non-null      float64       
 3   feature 2        4 non-null      datetime64[ns]
 4   feature 3        5 non-null      object        
 5   feature 4        6 non-null      float64       
dtypes: datetime64[ns](2), float64(2), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 464.0+ bytes
```

**Option 2: Auto detect and convert column type**

To automatically determine the data type, you need to write a function for determining the data type.

```
def dtype_inplace(df):
    from pandas.errors import ParserError
    for c in df.columns[df.dtypes=='object']:
        try:
            df[c]=pd.to_datetime(df[c], format='%d-%m-%Y')
        except (ParserError,ValueError):
            try:
                df[c]=df[c].astype(float)
            except (ParserError,ValueError):
                pass
    return df

dtype_inplace(df)
```

Returns

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 7 entries, 0 to 6
Data columns (total 6 columns):
 #   Column           Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------           --------------  -----         
 0   Startdate        7 non-null      datetime64[ns]
 1   personal number  7 non-null      int64         
 2   feature 1        4 non-null      float64       
 3   feature 2        4 non-null      datetime64[ns]
 4   feature 3        5 non-null      object        
 5   feature 4        6 non-null      float64       
dtypes: datetime64[ns](2), float64(2), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 464.0+ bytes
```